# Links in lists- getting a consistent a:hover effect

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists, bullet

when I create a list of links and give those links an a:hover state, I want the entire link, including the bullet point, to highlight on hover. But what because my list has a defined width which is wider than the As, the LIs pick up the :hover and change color before the As do. This looks messy! Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/NgWLR/

See what I mean? It's like the A & the LI are separate entities, triggering at different times.

If I try adding a display:block to the A styling, all I get is weird display issues in Firefox & a slight improvement in other browsers, but it certainly doesn't solve the problem.

I can change the list-style-type to none and put a :before bullet entity on my LIs, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/tScnS/2/

And that seems to work fine, in Safari & Firefox at least, but as a solution it seems kind of rough/messy/unlikely to be supported in all browsers.

Anyone know a 'bullet-proof' (hah!) way to get this to work, or should I just go ahead and implement in the manner of the 2nd JSfiddle- list-style-none, bullet :before?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `li:hover a` instead of `a:hover` to style the link, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/NgWLR/2/

*PS: Please remove remove unrelated code when showing examples.*

Comment: Sorry for the extra code, and thank you, this is the clear & simple fix I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

As per i understand remove `display:block` from your `<a>` tag. LIke this:

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/NgWLR/1/